# calculating mean by keeping all variable in the dataset in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to calculate the mean of time by keeping all the variables in the final dataset within `dplyr` package. 
Here how my sample dataset looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
id <-     c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4)
gender <- c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1)
item.id <-c(1,1,1,2, 1,1,2,2, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,2,3)
sequence<-c(1,2,3,1, 1,2,1,2, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,2,1)
time <-   c(5,6,7,1, 2,3,4,9, 1,2,3,9, 5,6,7,8)
data <- data.frame(id, gender, item.id, sequence, time)
> data
   id gender item.id sequence time
1   1      1       1        1    5
2   1      1       1        2    6
3   1      1       1        3    7
4   1      1       2        1    1
5   2      2       1        1    2
6   2      2       1        2    3
7   2      2       2        1    4
8   2      2       2        2    9
9   3      2       1        1    1
10  3      2       2        1    2
11  3      2       3        1    3
12  3      2       4        1    9
13  4      1       1        1    5
14  4      1       2        1    6
15  4      1       2        2    7
16  4      1       3        1    8
```

`id` for student id, `gender` for gender, `item.id` for the question ids students take, `sequence` is the sequence number of attempts to solve the question because students might return back to questions and try to answer again, and `time` is the time spent on each trial.

When calculating the mean of the time, I need to follow three steps:

`(a)` students have multiple trials for each question. I need to calculate the mean of the time for each item having multiple trials.

`(b)` then calculate the overall mean of the time for each `id`. For example, for `id=1`, I have two items, the first item has 3 trials and the second item has 1 trial. First I need to aggregate the time for the first item by `(5+6+7)/3=6`, so `id=1` has item1 time `6` and item2 time `1`. Second, taking `6` and `1` and calculating the mean for this student `(6+1)/2=3.5`.

`(c)` Lastly, I would like to keep all the variables in the dataset.

```
 data <- data %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          select(id, gender, item.id, sequence, time) %>%
          summarize(mean.time = mean(time))
```

I got this but obviously this is only aggregating the mean by not taking into account of the within mean for each trial and this also does not keep all the variables:

```
> data
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id mean.time
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      4.75
2     2      4.5 
3     3      3.75
4     4      6.5
```

I thought `select()` was going to keep all variables.

The final dataset should look like this below:

```
> data
   id gender item.id sequence time  mean.time
1   1      1       1        1    5    3.5
2   1      1       1        2    6    3.5
3   1      1       1        3    7    3.5
4   1      1       2        1    1    3.5
5   2      2       1        1    2    4.5
6   2      2       1        2    3    4.5
7   2      2       2        1    4    4.5
8   2      2       2        2    5    4.5
9   3      2       1        1    1    3.75
10  3      2       2        1    2    3.75
11  3      2       3        1    3    3.75
12  3      2       4        1    9    3.75
13  4      1       1        1    5    6.5
14  4      1       2        1    6    6.5
15  4      1       2        2    7    6.5
16  4      1       3        1    8    6.5
```

I used `dplyr` but open any other solutions. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate` instead of `summarise` as `summarise` returns a summarised output of 1 row per each group, while `mutate` creates a new column in the dataset

```
...
  %>% 
      mutate(mean.time = mean(time))
```

---

If wee want to get the `mean` of `mean`, then first group by 'id', 'item.id', get the `mean`, and then grouped by 'id', get the `mean` of `unique` elements

```
data %>%
   group_by(id, item.id) %>% 
   mutate(mean.time = mean(time)) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(mean.time = mean(unique(mean.time)))
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   id [4]
#      id gender item.id sequence  time mean.time
#   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1      1       1        1     5      3.5 
# 2     1      1       1        2     6      3.5 
# 3     1      1       1        3     7      3.5 
# 4     1      1       2        1     1      3.5 
# 5     2      2       1        1     2      4.5 
# 6     2      2       1        2     3      4.5 
# 7     2      2       2        1     4      4.5 
# 8     2      2       2        2     9      4.5 
# 9     3      2       1        1     1      3.75
#10     3      2       2        1     2      3.75
#11     3      2       3        1     3      3.75
#12     3      2       4        1     9      3.75
#13     4      1       1        1     5      6.5 
#14     4      1       2        1     6      6.5 
#15     4      1       2        2     7      6.5 
#16     4      1       3        1     8      6.5
```

Or instead of creating a second group by, we can do a `match` to get the first position of 'item.id', extract the 'mean.time' and get the `mean`

```
data %>%
   group_by(id, item.id) %>% 
   mutate(mean.time = mean(time), 
          mean.time = mean(mean.time[match(unique(item.id), item.id)]))
```

---

Or use `summarise` and then do a `left_join`

```
data %>%
  group_by(id, item.id) %>%
  summarise(mean.time = mean(time)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean.time = mean(mean.time)) %>%
  right_join(data)
```

Comment: I see. then, how can I take the within sequence mean into account? Could you take a look at the example after `(a)` and `(b)` ?

Comment: actually one more thing. When you use `unique(mean.time)`, it eliminates the repetitive values.  What if some questions have the same `mean.time` values?

Comment: @amisos55 It will return the same value i.e. `mean(c(5, 5))`

Comment: let's say `mean.time <- c(2,3,4,4,5,5,6)`. taking the mean `mean(mean.time)= 4.14`, but excluding the repetitive values and taking the mean with `unique()` it gives `mean(unique(mean.time)) = 4`. Is there a way to do it without the `unique()`?

Comment: @amisos55 In that case, the join solutiion should work, right?

Comment: @amisos55 I added one more approach - solid with `match`